Confusion between relation of stars and bars and q-binomial coefficient
Suppose we want to know the number of integer solutions to the equation $$x_1 + \cdots x_m = N$$ where $0 \leq x_i \leq t - 1$ for $1 \leq i \leq m$. One way to do this is by finding the coefficient of $q^N$ in the expansion of $$(1 + q + \cdots q^{t-1})^m = \left(\frac{1-q^t}{1-q}\right)^m.$$ On the other hand, another way to think about this is the number of partitions of $N$ with at most $m$ parts each of size at most $t - 1$. This corresponds to the coefficient of $q^N$ in $$\begin{bmatrix}m + t-1\\m\end{bmatrix}_q = \frac{\prod_{j = 1}^{m+t-1}(1-q^j)}{\prod_{j = 1}^{t-1}(1-q^j)\prod_{j = 1}^{m}(1-q^j)}.$$ However these two quantities are not equal so I am not sure where my misinterpretation is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

distinct $m$ objects in $x_1 + \cdots x_m = N$ vs identical $m$ objects in partitions

This isn't true. If we look at the case $t=3, m=2$ then the first polynomial is
$$(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2)=1+2x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4$$
whereas the second polynomial is
$$(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2)=1+x+2x^2+x^3+x^4$$
The first counts compositions, e.g.

0
01,10
02,11,20
12,21
22

and the second counts partitions

0
1
11,2
21
22

